# How to recreate the 'Cut Copy' Popover on the iPad?

Tags: ipad

The 'Cut Copy ...' interface popover that displays on the iPad -- I want to create my own popover that is displayed similarly, but I can't determine how theirs was implemented.

It looks like a UISegmentedControl with some styling, which should be easy to implement, but whenever I create a popover and put a view inside it, I can't seem to remove the popover border. Basically, what I want is a popover that has the aesthetic of a UISegmentedControl (e.g. contains the popover arrow as well). This must be easy, as I see it done all over the place. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIMenuController is what I was looking for.